# VSCode navigation keybinding for command picker

Tags: key-bindings, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know whether there is a keybinding to navigate up and down in VSCode's Command Picker(Ctrl+Shift+P).

[image: VSCode Show All Commands palette]

I can navigate using the up arrow and down arrow buttons, but I want to bind up and down to ctrl+i, ctrl+j.

---

There seems like navigation keybinding for **QuickOpen** `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext` but I can't find one for **Show All Commands** palette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by changing the `Navigate Previous in Quick Open` and `Navigate Next in Quick Open` to your choice of keys respectively.

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Should be noted that you likely want to add !textInputFocus or a whole list of modes (inQuickOpen || inEditorsPicker || inRecentFilesPicker || ...) for the When clause of this binding to avoid overlap with the same binding in other areas of the UI.